# How do I create a MAX value for column referring to another table's column

Tags: django, sqlite

```
class Agent(models.Model):
nickname = models.CharField(max_length=64)
club_agent_id = models.IntegerField()
club = models.ForeignKey(
    Club, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="agents")
**rakeback** = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=3)
user = models.ForeignKey(
    User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="agents")

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.nickname} - {self.club} - {self.rakeback}"


class Account(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    club_account_id = models.IntegerField()
    **rakeback** = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=3)
    club = models.ManyToManyField(Club, blank=True, related_name="accounts")
    agent = models.ManyToManyField(Agent, related_name="accounts")

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.club_account_id} - {self.nickname}"
```

Here the program will create Agent and Account are tied to it. Account belongs to Agent. Agent has many Accounts. When creating Agent, the rakeback value is set by the User.

How do I set MAX for **rakeback** on Account referring to the value of **rakeback** on Agent?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`annotate`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/) with **`Max`**, like this:

```
from django.db.models import Max

accounts =  Account.objects.annotate(rakeback=Max('agent__rakeback'))
print(accounts.values('pk', 'rakeback'))
```

You do not need to keep the `rakeback` field in `Account` model.